# How do I convert plain text to parsable text (with the percentage symbols between each word)?

Tags: python, text-parsing, text-formatting

I have plain text that I'm passing into an API but the text has the euro symbol (€) in it which throws an error. However, when I pass in the text to a test function on the APIs website (GrammarBot), it converts the € symbol into a readable one. Here is the conversion:

**Input**: "In Germany, millions of people applied to join a study of universal basic income that will provide participants with €1,200 ($1,423) a month, while in the United Kingdom, more than 100 lawmakers — including Jardine — are pushing the government to start similar trials.
Austria, meanwhile, has launched a first-of-its-kind pilot program that will guarantee paying jobs to residents struggling with sustained unemployment in Marienthal, a long-suffering former industrial town about 40 miles southwest of Vienna.
Whether the spike in popularity and research will translate into a wave of action is an open question. But some, like Jardine, see reason for optimism."

**Output**: "In%20Germany%2C%20millions%20of%20people%20applied%20to%20join%20a%20study%20of%20universal%20basic%20income%20that%20will%20provide%20participants%20with%20%E2%82%AC1%2C200%20(%241%2C423)%20a%20month%2C%20while%20in%20the%20United%20Kingdom%2C%20more%20than%20100%20lawmakers%20%E2%80%94%20including%20Jardine%20%E2%80%94%20are%20pushing%20the%20government%20to%20start%20similar%20trials.%20Austria%2C%20meanwhile%2C%20has%20launched%20a%20first-of-its-kind%20pilot%20program%20that%20will%20guarantee%20paying%20jobs%20to%20residents%20struggling%20with%20sustained%20unemployment%20in%20Marienthal%2C%20a%20long-suffering%20former%20industrial%20town%20about%2040%20miles%20southwest%20of%20Vienna.%20Whether%20the%20spike%20in%20popularity%20and%20research%20will%20translate%20into%20a%20wave%20of%20action%20is%20an%20open%20question.%20But%20some%2C%20like%20Jardine%2C%20see%20reason%20for%20optimism."

I'm not even sure what the terminology is for this type of conversion but does anyone have a solution on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's called URL encoding. You should use the [`quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) function from `urllib.parse`

```
from urllib.parse import quote

s = "In Germany, millions of people applied to join a study of universal basic income that will provide participants with €1,200 ($1,423) a month..."

print(quote(s, safe='/()'))
```

Results in:

```
In%20Germany%2C%20millions%20of%20people%20applied%20to%20join%20a%20study%20of%20universal%20basic%20income%20that%20will%20provide%20participants%20with%20%E2%82%AC1%2C200%20(%241%2C423)%20a%20month%2C%20while%20
```

The `safe` argument tells it to not encode some chars that are deemed "safe to skip". in your case I see that `()` are not encoded so I've added them to `safe`